# Codewars Kata in C erratic behaviour for dice roll

Tags: c

I have an issue with my C code in this Codewars Problem:

> Greed is a dice game played with five six-sided dice. Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to score a throw according to these rules. You will always be given an array with five six-sided dice values.
>
> Three `1`'s (⚀) => 1000 points
> Three `6`'s (⚅) =>  600 points
> Three `5`'s (⚄) =>  500 points
> Three `4`'s (⚃) =>  400 points
> Three `3`'s (⚂) =>  300 points
> Three `2`'s (⚁) =>  200 points
> One   `1` (⚀)   =>  100 points
> One   `5` (⚄)   =>   50 points
>
> A single die can only be counted once in each roll. For example, a given `5` can only count as part of a triplet (contributing to the 500 points) or as a single 50 points, but not both in the same roll.
>
> Example scoring
>
> Throw       Score
> ---------------------------
> `5 1 3 4 1`   250:  50 (for the `5`) + 2 * 100 (for the `1`s)
> `1 1 1 3 1`   1100: 1000 (for three `1`s) + 100 (for the other `1`)
> `2 4 4 5 4`   450:  400 (for three `4`s) + 50 (for the `5`)
>
> In some languages, it is possible to mutate the input to the function. This is something that you should never do. If you mutate the input, you will not be able to pass all the tests.

My solution looks like this:

```
int score(const int dice[5]) {
    int score = 0;
    int digits[6] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        digits[dice[i]]++;
    }
    // Rules
    // 100 points for each 1 except when there is more than 2
    if (digits[1] < 3) {
        score += digits[1] * 100;    
    } else {
        score += (digits[1] % 3) * 100;
    }
    // 50 points for each 5
    if (digits[5] < 3) {
        score += digits[5] * 50;    
    } else {
        score += (digits[5] % 3) * 50;
    }
    // 1000 points for 3 1s
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        int repeats = digits[i];
        if (repeats >= 3) {
            switch (i) {
              case 1:
                score += 1000;
                break;
              case 2:
                score += 200;
                break;
              case 3:
                score += 300;
                break;
              case 4:
                score += 400;
                break;
              case 5:
                score += 500;
                break;
              case 6:
                score += 600;
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

Sometimes, the tests pass OK, but then it will not pass the same tests for no apparent reason. The code runs well with all tests on my machine, so I suspect that I have introduced a machine/compiler dependent bug that arises when Codewars runs it. It would be amazing if someone could point me to it.

I tried to rerun it on my machine with all successful results. The problem can be found in Codewars,
[here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5270d0d18625160ada0000e4/train/c)

Comment: `digits` is an array that goes from 0 to 5, but you write and read from 1 to 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `int digits[6] = { 0 };` should actually be defined with 7 entries so you can access `digits[6]` for dice showing a `6`:

```
    int digits[7] = { 0 };
```

As posted, the code has undefined behavior when there is a `6` in the throw.

With this correction, your approach should work fine.

Note also that the code can be further simplified:

```
int score(const int dice[5]) {
    int score = 0;
    int digits[7] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        digits[dice[i]]++;
    }
    // Rules:
    // 100 points for each 1 except for a group of 3
    score += (digits[1] % 3) * 100;

    // 50 points for each 5 except for a group of 3
    score += (digits[5] % 3) * 50;

    // account for groups of 3:
    score += 1000 * (digits[1] / 3);  // 1000 for 3 ones
    score += 200 * (digits[2] / 3);   // 200 for 3 twos
    score += 300 * (digits[3] / 3);   // 300 for 3 threes
    score += 400 * (digits[4] / 3);   // 400 for 3 fours
    score += 500 * (digits[5] / 3);   // 500 for 3 fives
    score += 600 * (digits[6] / 3);   // 600 for 3 sixes

    return score;
}
```

Alternately, you can use a parameterized approach, separating the algorithm from the scores:

```
int score(const int dice[5]) {
    // 100 for each 1 and 50 for each 5
    int score[7] = { 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0 };
    // bonus points for groups of 3
    int bonus[7] = { 0, 700, 200, 300, 400, 350, 600 };
    int digits[7] = { 0 };
    int score = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // sanity check
        if (dice[i] < 1 || dice[i] > 6)
            return -1;
        // count the dice by value
        digits[dice[i]]++;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        score += digits[i] * score[i];
        score += (digits[i] / 3) * bonus[i];
    }
    return score;
}
```